# Existence of a solution for non-linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Given the two non-linear equations
$$2\sin(x)-2\sin(a-x)+\sin(a)=0,\\
2\cos(x)-2\cos(a-x)+\cos(a)-1=0,
$$
where $0<a<2\pi$ and $0<x<a/2$. Is there a way to show that for arbitrary $a$, $x$ always *exits* such that both equations hold (I don't need an explicit expression for $x$, just its existence)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's just easier to search for a solution than work towards a non-constructive proof.

Comment: Do you mean, like for any $a$, there always exists an $x$ satisfying both equations. Or do you mean like, there exists ordered pairs $(x, a)$ satisfying both equations

Comment: If you are allowed to pick any $a,x$, then there are many solutions. Notably, when $a=\pi$, the first equation holds regardless of $x$, so pick the appropriate $x$ to satisfy the second equation.

Comment: I would say, simplify at first the given system.

Comment: @DonThousand Indeed I would like it to be true for arbitrary $a$, edited the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two equations can be expanded as
$$-2\sin a\cos x+2(1+\cos a)\sin x+\sin a=0,\\
2(1-\cos a)\cos x+2\sin a\sin x+\cos a-1=0$$

or

$$-2\cos x+2\frac{1+\cos a}{\sin a}\sin x+1=0,\\
-2\cos x-2\frac{\sin a}{\cos a-1}\sin x+1=0.$$

The rest is yours.

Comment: And what if $$\sin(a)=0$$ or $$\cos(a)=1$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: left to the reader as an exercise.

Comment: Cheers, should have realised to use the identities myself...I think it should be a minus though for the second one in front of $\sin x$.

Comment: @JDecou: yep, it must be for the coefficients to be equal. Fixing.